# Gmail API refuses delegated email's request

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I have a realusername@gmail.com email address and I have a delegated one delegateusername@gmail.com

I can reach the delegated account if I log in with realusername through the gmail application, but if want to do the same with gmail-api, it refuses.

I call this:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/delegateusername@gmail.com/labels?key={MY_API_KEY}

after I authenticate with realusername and I receive this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Delegation denied for realusername@gmail.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Delegation denied for realusername@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

It shoud work, not?

Could someone help me why it happen, or what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Use `"me"` as `userId` instead. You still need a [access token from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670006/access-delegated-mail-folder-with-gmail-api).

Comment: It is not good for me, becasue if use "me" I will receive the realusername's labels, but I wana get the delegateusername's labels

Comment: I understand :) See the answer I linked. Delegation in the Gmail API does not work in the same way as the web ui.

Comment: In this case for me it seems the "userId" is fully useless, because it has to be always "me", so it is bug, not?

Comment: That's a good point. I don't know to be honest, since I've never used a delegated request. Hopefully a Google pro can answer.

Comment: did you do this? https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.create_delegated

Comment: The email address is useful when you make a request to the API using domain wide delegation. I am now also trying to make the same request from a Chrome Extension with only delegated access and I get the same error.