# Gmail SendAs Settings for Delegated Accounts

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to get the signature for a delegated account using the new User.settings capabilities in the Gmail API.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/get

I have two accounts in the same Apps org but with different domain names. In the Gmail UI, I log in via my "primary" account and in the accounts list I see the "secondary" account with "(delegated)" appearing after the email address.

However, if I try and do this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/secondary%40domainB.com/settings/sendAs/secondary%40domainB.com?key={MY_API_KEY}
```

I get this 403 error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Delegation denied for primary@domainA.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Delegation denied for primary@domainA.com"
 }
}
```

Is this not supported or am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

did you gave the domain wide delegation to your service account?

Comment: I was actually just using the test form on the above link to the API pages rather than a service account. Good point though - it would be a service account in production so I'll give it a try.

Comment: did you made your manipulations with an admin account on the domains ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm a super-admin for the whole organsation.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API does not currently support access by delegates (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670632/3377170)).  You need to either use 3LO credentials or service account credentials with domain-wide delegation.